# Tkinter фоновое изображение окна

Tags: python, tkinter, pillow, tkinter-faq

Как в Tkinter задать фоновое изображение всего окна? Чтобы все кнопки были поверх

Comment: Однако если использовать Label то фон виджета нельзя НИКАК сделать прозрачным. Тогда есть решение через самодельную прорисовку виджетов и `bind`-inga событий

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

def show_image(path):
    root = tk.Tk()
    img = Image.open(path)
    width = 500
    ratio = (width / float(img.size[0]))
    height = int((float(img.size[1]) * float(ratio)))
    imag = img.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imag)
    panel = tk.Label(root, image=image)
    panel.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="no")

    tk.Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit).place(x=250, y=250)

    root.mainloop()

show_image('D:/_Qt/img/cat.jpg')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @FiolDoll нужно установить библиотеку `pip install pillow`

Answer (score 0):

Вариант добавления фоновой картинки через Canvas. Кнопку размещаем с помощью метода `create_window`. Для создания текста с прозрачным фоном вместо `Label` используем `create_text`.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

path = 'cat.jpg'

root = tk.Tk()

# Загружаем изображение и пропорционально изменяем размер так,
# чтобы ширина была 500px.
# Если изменение размера не нужно, оставьте только строки
# image = Image.open(path)
# и
# image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
image = Image.open(path)
width = 500
ratio = (width / float(image.size[0]))
height = int((float(image.size[1]) * float(ratio)))
image = image.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=width, height=height)
canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="no")

canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=image)

# Создаем кнопку и размещяем ее в "окне" ("контейнере") на Canvas
button = tk.Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit)
canvas.create_window((250, 250), anchor="nw", window=button)

# Создаем текст через create_text, в отличие от Label у него будет прозрачный фон
canvas.create_text(100, 100, text="Cat", fill="Yellow", font="Verdana 14")

root.mainloop()
```

[image: Скриншот]