# Как в Tkinter сделать текст Label прозрачным?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

[image: В правом нижнем углу видно, что текст имеет "рамку".]

Если я уберу bg из кода, то такая рамка будет белой, а не пропадёт вовсе. Как можно сделать обычный текст без рамки?

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Вкратце: через Label - никак. Только делать фон через Canvas, на нем рисовать текст через create_text. Пример с create_text см тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1229758/1365