# как поставить фон в виде картинке что бы она маштабировалась с остальными кнопками?

Tags: tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Frame
```

```
class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.master.title("текс")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        window = Frame(self)
        window.pack(fill=X)

        btn1 = Button(window, text="Открыть браузер", bg="#0006FF", fg="#BBE6FF", activebackground="blue",
                      activeforeground="black", bd=3)
        btn1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        btn2 = Button(window, text="текс", bg="#0006FF", fg="#BBE6FF", activebackground="blue",
                      activeforeground="black", bd=3)
        btn2.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        btn3 = Button(window, text="текс", bg="#0006FF", fg="#BBE6FF", activebackground="blue",
                      activeforeground="black", bd=3)
        btn3.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5, pady=5)

        ent1 = Entry(window, width=100, bg="#0006FF", bd=5, fg="#BBE6FF", selectbackground="black")
        ent1.pack(fill=X, padx=5, expand=True)

        window1 = Frame(self)
        window1.pack(fill=X)

        lbl1 = Label(window1, text="текс", width=10)
        lbl1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        window2 = Frame(self)
        window2.pack(fill=X)

        ent2 = Entry(window2, width=10, bg="#0006FF", bd=5, fg="#BBE6FF", selectbackground="black")
        ent2.pack(side=LEFT, anchor=N, padx=5, pady=5)

        window3 = Frame(self)
        window3.pack(fill=X)

        lbl2 = Label(window3, text="текс", width=10)
        lbl2.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        window4 = Frame(self)
        window4.pack(fill=X)

        ent3 = Entry(window4, width=10, bg="#0006FF", bd=5, fg="#BBE6FF", selectbackground="black")
        ent3.pack(side=LEFT, anchor=N, padx=5, pady=5)

        window5 = Frame(self)
        window5.pack(fill=X)

        lbl3 = Label(window5, text="текс", width=8)
        lbl3.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        window6 = Frame(self)
        window6.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
```

```
def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry()
    app = Example()
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
root = Tk()
root.title("GUI на Python")
root.geometry("500x500")

btn = Button(text="Hello")
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Пробовал вписать в функцию, но почему то не показывает фон,
а в отдельном файле, показывает. Убираю класс `app = Example()`
и все работает.

Comment: Не очень понятно, что надо, Как вставлять картинку на фон, можно тут прочитать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1056539/tkinter-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0

Comment: Как добавить это в мой код?