# Фоновая картинка перекрывает все кнопки и надписи

Tags: python, tkinter, gui, разметка

Делаю приложение на tkinter и хочу поставить картинку в качестве фона и на нее все остальные кнопки и надписи. У меня что-то не получается и картинка перекрывает все остальное. Вот код ниже:

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry('1920x1080')
root.title('QuizOp')
root['bg'] = 'limegreen'



generalframe = Frame(master=root, bg='limegreen')

bgimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("stestimage.jpg"))

bglabel = Label(root, image=bgimage)

createquizbtn = Button(generalframe, bg='white', text='Создать викторину', font='Arial 17', command=createquiz)
proitiquizbtn = Button(generalframe, bg='white', text='Пройти викторину', font='Arial 17', command=proitiquiz)
sendquizbtn = Button(generalframe, bg='white', text='Отправить викторину', font='Arial 17', command=sendquiz)
deletequizbtn = Button(generalframe, bg='white', text='Удалить викторину', font='Arial 17', command=deletequiz)
settingsbtn = Button(generalframe, bg='white', text='Настройки', font='Arial 17', command=settingscmd)


bglabel.pack()


generalframe.pack()
createquizbtn.pack()
proitiquizbtn.pack()
sendquizbtn.pack()
deletequizbtn.pack()
settingsbtn.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Размещайте фоновую картинку через `place(x=0, y=0)`.

Comment: То же самое. Фон все закрывает и кнопок нет. Я написал ```bglabel.place(x=0, y=0)``` вместо ```bglabel.pack()```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, z-order (порядок, в котором виджеты размещаются друг поверх друга) зависит от того, в каком порядке они созданы (но не от того, в каком порядке вызваны методы размещения place/pack/grid). Из-за того, что `Label` с картинкой создается после `generalframe`, `Label` размещается поверх этого фрейма.

В таком варианте должно работать:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.geometry('1920x1080')
root.title('QuizOp')

# Сначала создаем картинку в окне, потом уже фрейм,
# тогда фрейм будет размещаться поверх картинки
bgimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("stestimage.jpg"))
bglabel = Label(root, image=bgimage)

generalframe = Frame(master=root, bg='limegreen')

...

bglabel.place(x=0, y=0)
generalframe.pack()

...
```

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Нет ли варианта чтобы generalframe стал прозрачным? Или нужно переписывать мастера кнопок под root? (код кстати сработал)

Comment: @retr12 кнопки только перемещать на тот же объект, где картинка размещена. Если еще Label где-то, то они тоже не могут быть прозрачными. Для текста с прозрачным фоном нужно использовать Canvas, и добавлять текст через метод create_text, см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1229758/1365

Comment: Если ответ помог, вы можете отметить его принятым, для этого поставьте галку слева от ответа.