# Помогите, как на фон программы вставить любую картинку или гифку?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *


def func():
    tex.delete(1.0, END)
    N = int(ent.get())
    F = N
    for i in range(2, F):
        if F%i==0:
            d=0 
            for B in range(2, i):
                if i % B ==0:
                    d+= 1
            if d == 0:
                por = 0 
                while N % i ==0:
                    por += 1
                    N=N//i
                
                #print("делитель",i,"порядок",por)
                s=f"делитель {i}, порядок {por}"
                tex.insert("end", s)

                
def delete_text():
    tex.delete(1.0, END)                
                #tex = Text(root,width=40,
                         #  font="Verdana 12",
                          # wrap=WORD) 
                
def close_win():
     root.destroy()

               
                
root = Tk()   #главный экран

root.title('1.6 Разложение числа на простые множители')#название главного окна
root.geometry('700x300')
root.resizable(width = False, height = False)
root['bg'] = '#ff2400'
   


lab1 =  Label(root, text = 'Разложить целое число на простые множители. \n Вывести на экран все простые множители \n (в порядке возрастания) и их порядки.',background = "#ff2400", font = 'Arial 12')

lab2 = Label(root, text = 'Введите n:',background = "#ff2400", font = 'Arial 12 bold')
ent = Entry(root) 

but = Button(root) 

but1 = Button(text = 'Разложить',background = "#ff2400", command = func, font = 'Arial 12')
tex = Text(width = 18, height =5 , font = 'Arial 12')

but2 = Button(text="Удалить",background = "#ff2400", command=delete_text)
but3= Button(text="Выход",background = "#ff2400", command=close_win, font = 'Arial 14').place(relx=0.1, rely=0.8)
lab1.pack()
lab2.pack()
ent.pack()
but1.pack()
tex.pack()
but2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Что вы попробовали сделать и что пошло не так?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1056539/tkinter-фоновое-изображение-окна